# Parse weird response with refit

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, refit

I have an API response which is an array containing an object and an array like below:

```
[
  {
    "questions": [
      {
        "type": 3
      },
      {
        "type": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  []
]
```

I tried parsing like this but got no luck:

```
public class TableDetailResponse
    {
        public QuestionTable Table { get; set; }
        public List<object> Errors { get; set; }
    }

public class QuestionTable
    {
        [JsonProperty("questions")]
        public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
    }

public class Question
    {
        [JsonProperty("type")]
        public int Type { get; set; }
    }
```

```
using Refit;


public interface SOJOSurveyService
    {
        [Get("/survey/{id}")]
        Task<TableDetailResponse> QueryQuestionsByFlow([AliasAs("id")] string questionID);
    }
```

How to parse the above json?

Comment: That response does not look valid. An array of what might be an object and might be an empty array. Not sure why any response would look like that, but I don;t think refit will have a good time with it, but you'll at very least need the response to look like something enumerable for refit to stand a chance.

Comment: @Jamiec thank you for your comment. Sadly I have no choice but to parse that JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your root result is actually JSON array which has elements of different types. Assuming that you are using Newtonsoft Json.NET (based on the tags) you have basically two options - "dynamic" deserialization or custom converter. First option would be a bit easier, to get you started:

```cs
Task<JArray> QueryQuestionsByFlow(...);
```

And then deserialize:

```cs
var js_str = """
[
  {
    "questions": [
      {
        "type": 3
      },
      {
        "type": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  []
]
""";

var tokens = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(js_str);

var questionTable = (tokens[0] as JObject) // or iterate and check the node type - tokens[1].Type == JTokenType.Object ...
    .ToObject<QuestionTable>();
Console.WriteLine(questionTable.Questions.Count); // prints "2"
```

Custom converter approach will be doing something similar.

But I would recommend looking into fixing the called API. While the JSON itself is valid, the format is definitely not consumer-friendly.

Comment: thank you very much. Unfortunately I have no permission to modify the called API

Comment: @manaclan was glad to help! But I would at least try to verify that this is not a bug on the API side.